# Wrong ruby executable path in Tmux session

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, tmux

I've installed `ruby 2.0` by using `rvm`. I am new to `tmux`.

I am using zsh in the `.tmux.conf` with this config

```
set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh 
set-option -g default-command "/bin/zsh -i"
```

also I've loaded rvm path in `.zshrc`

```
source /Users/mgpyone/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Now, These are the configs when I try **within the `tmux` session.**

`which ruby` says `/Users/mgpyone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby`

`where ruby` returns as

```
/Users/mgpyone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby 
/Users/mgpyone/.rvm/bin/ruby 
/Users/mgpyone/.rvm/bin/ruby
```

but why `gem env` shows my `Ruby executable` path is set to System path instead of `rvm`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-02-24 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/mgpyone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/mgpyone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/mgpyone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
     - /Users/mgpyone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :benchmark => false
     - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org
```

And I can't run things like `rake` because I think it went and execute with System Ruby.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby app.rb -s puma
app.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- sinatra (LoadError)
        from app.rb:1
        rake aborted!
        Command failed with status (1): [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]
        /Users/mgpyone/work/rb/fileserver/Rakefile:9
        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Just check whether the `gem` command is using the system gem or rvm gem. Also, is this only happening when you use tmux?

Comment: How can I check whether `gem` command is using system gem or rvm gem? Yes, it only happes when I am in `tmux` session. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just with `which gem`. Maybe try changing the tmux default command to `"/bin/zsh -l"` - you need a login shell to source the zshrc.

Comment: When I run `which gem` inside the tmux session, it says `/usr/bin/gem` . When I run the same thing in outside `zsh` shell it says like this http://pastebin.com/fQLmA5Xm . I've already change to `/bin/zsh -l`

Comment: If you `source ~/.zshrc` explicitly inside your tmux session does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's showing like this http://i.imgur.com/PNN4WDP.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30480/discussion-between-jonathan-cairns-and-ye-lin-aung)

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you had $GEM_HOME or $GEM_PATH set when you started tmux. With tmux inheriting these environment variables, every shell that is contained under it will be affected with those settings regardless of rvm setup.

Check with `tmux showenv -g GEM_HOME` (or GEM_PATH)

Comment: so -- this is definitely the problem I'm facing. But it seems like RVM set $GEM_HOME for me automatically: